# colorbox close confirmation

Tags: jquery, colorbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#rest').colorbox();
$("#cboxClose").click(function(){ $.fn.colorbox.close(); });
var cboxClose = $.fn.colorbox.close;
$.fn.colorbox.close = function(){ if(confirm("Are you sure?")) { cboxClose(); } }
});
```

this code close my jquery colorbox when i confirm the dialog, but if i click on cancel (!confirm) its as closing

what im doing wrong?

Comment: //  $close.click(publicMethod.close);
i commented this line and now its working...

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done a little simpler

```
$(function(){

    $('#rest').colorbox();

      // If close button is clicked...
    $("#cboxClose").click(function(){ 

          // Confirm desire to close, and only close if confirmed
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){ $.colorbox.close(); };
    });

});
```

Note:
**[`$(function() { ... });` is synonymous with `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**

Comment: Hey Peter: Unfortunately, with your method, the colorbox also closes either way, clicking "OK" or "CANCEL" has the same effect. :-(
(Tested in: Firefox 4, IE 8)